# enabling ccache in ubuntu for android development

Tags: android, bashrc

http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#choosing-a-branch

following the instruction, I installed ccache and edited .bashrc with export USE_CCACHE=1

but when I start a build, and typed ccache -s in another terminal, i do not see cache hit. Did I do something wrong?